# USB CC2531 Unsupported device on Linux 4.9 aarch64

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, arm

I try to use [zigbee2mqtt](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/) using the CC2531 USB stick.
I tried on two computers:

- On my laptop running ArchLinux (x86_64) (kernel 5.2). Every thing it works as expected (device recognized on `dmesg`, zigbee2mqtt working: zigbee devices appears on the log)
- On my odroid-n2 (a single board computer) running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS or  ArchLinuxARM (kernel 4.9) (aarch64). `zigbee2mqtt` starts, but no zigbee device is detected on both Ubuntu and ArchLinuxARM.

From now on, every command is executed on the odroid.

```bsh
sudo dmesg | grep -i usb
[  115.960507] usb 1-1.1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci-hcd
[  116.064565] usb 1-1.1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=16a8
[  116.064578] usb 1-1.1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  116.064585] usb 1-1.1.1: Product: TI CC2531 USB CDC
[  116.064593] usb 1-1.1.1: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
[  116.064600] usb 1-1.1.1: SerialNumber: __0X00124B001938A33F
[  116.087026] usb 1-1.1.1: Unsupported device
[  116.087333] usb 1-1.1.1: Unsupported device
[  116.125408] cdc_acm 1-1.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  116.126816] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[  116.126822] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

The *Unsupported device* makes me suspect a driver issue but when I unplug and replug the cc2531, I no longer have the *Unsupported device* in `dmesg` (I have to reboot to get this error again).

```bsh
ls -l /dev/ttyACM0                                                                                                                                   odroid@odroid 0s 
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 juil. 16 11:58 /dev/ttyACM0
```

```bsh
groups odroid
odroid : odroid adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lightdm nopasswdlogin pulse-access docker
```

On the odroid, `zigbee2mqtt` doesn't log any error (I can even turn off the led of the cc2531 with a `zigbee2mqtt` parameter - [see this post](http://zigbee2mqtt.discourse.group/t/no-device-detected-for-pairing/160) for the full `zigbee2mqtt` log), but it doesn't detect any devices.

I tried to plug the stick directly on a USB port of the board, or using an externally powered hub. Every port is USB3 ports. The cc2531 behavior is the same on the hub and on the onboard hub.

I am not really sure if it is a driver issue, but I don't know what else could cause this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [to this video](https://training.ti.com/how-enable-usb-device-driver-processor-sdk-linux), I was able to identifiy the missing driver. I needed to enable the option `USB_SERIAL_TI` in `make menuconfig` before compiling the Linux kernel.

---

Step for finding the right option :

1. Identifying the `idVendor` of the USB stick using `dmesg`. In my case it is `0451`
2. Finding the driver file in the Linux kernel for this `idVendor`. My USB stick is made by Texas Instruments (TI in `dmesg`)

```
$ git clone --depth 1 --branch master https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git linux
...
$ cd linux
$ grep -i 0x0451 -r --include='*.c' drivers/
...
drivers/usb/serial/ti_usb_3410_5052.c:#define TI_VENDOR_ID          0x0451
...
```

3. The driver file might be `ti_usb_3410_5052.c`. Now I need to find wich option include this file during the Linux kernel compilation. I need to look for the make file in the same folder than `ti_usb_3410_5052.c`

```
$ cat drivers/usb/serial/Makefile | grep -i ti_usb_3410_5052
obj-$(CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_TI)         += ti_usb_3410_5052.o
```

4. The option is `USB_SERIAL_TI`. I can use `make menuconfig` to enable it.